# No Due Date Populated in Sandbox and Production

Tags: opportunity, tasks, log-a-call

When creating Log a Call activity in Opportunity Object in Lightning,the due date gets displayed with Today's date in Developer org.,wherein it gets displayed as "No Due Date" in Sandbox and Production Org.May I know why is it happening?Thanks in Advance.Please look into the image for reference.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a9CG.png]